# How to show occurences of child entries in the text as parent entries in the glossary?

Tags: glossaries

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[automake=immediate,symbols,nogroupskip,style=index]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{parent}{name={\ensuremath{x_i}}, description={this is an entry}}
\newglossaryentry{child1}{name={\ensuremath{x_1}}, parent={parent}, description={this is an entry}}
\newglossaryentry{child2}{name={\ensuremath{x_2}}, parent={parent}, description={this is an entry}}

\begin{document}

I have an indexed parent abbreviation \gls{parent} on the first page.

\clearpage

I have two children \gls{child1} and \gls{child2} on the second page.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

I get a glossary that looks like

[image]

I would like to leave the rest of the text in the current state and have only a single row in the dictionary which has a description of the parent and the occurences of the parent and all of its children, i.e.

xi this is an entry. 1,2